# One Observablecollection with different operations in two views

Tags: c#, wpf

I am facing one issue, where i have two controls and both of them shares a common Observablecollection, Two List boxes having a commomn Items Source ( common Observablecollection). Now when i have to clear the items from one ListBox (collection.Clear), i do not want to delete the items from the second List Box.
Cloning the collection and assign the clone collection as Itemsource of other ListBox solves my purpose, but if i delete any item from first collectection how to delete the same from its counterpart.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="canvasListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding VectorImages,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding ImageVectorSelected}"  BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">

<ListBox x:Name="ChildListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ClonedVectorImages,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding ImageVectorSelected}"  BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">

ViewModel -

VectorImages.Clear();

 private void DeleteVector()
        {
          VectorImages.Remove((ImageVector)_deleteCommand.Parameter);

           foreach (var item in VectorImages)
           {
             if (item.CountId > RemovedVectorCountId)
             {
                 item.CountId = item.CountId - 1;
             }
           }
           countId--;
        }
```

Comment: You need to create 2 views of that collection and you need to manipulate those views. once changes are completed you can commit your view on you collection in the model. But having 2 different lists i don't see why you would be saving this information in 1 collection only and not 2.

Comment: The object would need a unique identifier to delete.  As a clone it is a new object.  If you overwrite equals on the class then you should be able to do delete the "same" object from both.  DeleteVector() is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You should have two separate ObservableCollections, containing the *same* objects. So you can do `.Clear()` on one of the collections, without doing the same for the other. OTOH when you want to remove an item from both lists, you'll have to do it manually.

So when you have the item to remove: do `collection1.Remove(item)`, you can do the same for collection2 `collection2.Remove(item)`.

Comment: As i am deleting items through Command Binding. The Parameter of Remove(item) is not appearing to be same for both collections.  VectorImages.Remove((ImageVector)_deleteCommand.Parameter); if this is fired from first ListBox, Remove((ImageVector)_deleteCommand.Parameter) is not showing the same value for other ListBox.